# Creating a cron job to run at hour mark and half hour mark for specific hours on specific day of week

Tags: linux, unix, cron, cron-task

I need to setup cron jobs so that they run at
1800, 1830, 1900, 1930, 2000, 2030, 2100 on every Monday and Thursday.
So far I've managed to get to this:

```
00,30 18-21 * * 1,4
```

Is this the right way of doing it? If yes, will it run on 21:30 as well?

Comment: yes , they way you made it - it will run at 21:30 as well ...

Comment: So if I don't want to run it at 21:30, I need to split them up for 00 and 30 minutes?

Comment: the easiest way would be to simply make another fresh entry for the 21st hour ..... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cronjob will run at 21.30 as well. To avoid it, you'd better split it in two pieces:

```
00,30 18-20 * * 1,4     # 1800, 1830, 1900, 1930, 2000, 2030
00 21 * * 1,4           # 2100
```